# Event Hub Lease Management

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, cortana-intelligence

Does anyone know where I can find details about how event hub lease management works?  Specifically I'm trying to find how do I know where in the event hub the EventProcess picks up processing (after a reboot, shutdown, lease lost)? What is the best way to set the index to the beginning during development?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host) does a good job of explaining lease management in EventHub under distributed consuming applications :

> **Lease management**
>
> Registering an event processor class with an instance of
> EventProcessorHost starts event processing. The host instance obtains
> leases on some partitions of the Event Hub, possibly grabbing some
> from other host instances, in a way that converges on an even
> distribution of partitions across all host instances. For each leased
> partition, the host instance creates an instance of the provided event
> processor class, then receives events from that partition, and passes
> them to the event processor instance. As more instances get added and
> more leases are grabbed, EventProcessorHost eventually balances the
> load among all consumers.
>
> As explained previously, the tracking table greatly simplifies the
> autoscale nature of EventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync.
> As an instance of EventProcessorHost starts, it acquires as many
> leases as possible, and begins reading events. As the leases near
> expiration, EventProcessorHost attempts to renew them by placing a
> reservation. If the lease is available for renewal, the processor
> continues reading, but if it is not, the reader is closed and
> CloseAsync is called. CloseAsync is a good time to perform any final
> cleanup for that partition.
>
> EventProcessorHost includes a PartitionManagerOptions property. This
> property enables control over lease management. Set these options
> before registering your IEventProcessor implementation.